# How to search a list using multiple criteria and getting a best match?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to get a best match based on multiple criteria when searching through a list. The lists may or may not be the same length:

```
list1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
list2 = [10,15,20,25,30,35]
list3 = [10,12,15,18,20,30,40]

search_criteria = [10,20] # should return all three lists

search_criteria2 = [10,15,20,25] # should return list2 first and list 3 as a close match

search_criteria3 = [35] # only returns list 2

search_criteria4 = [10,80,100] # returns list1 as best match
```

I have thought of using list comprehensions:

```
listmatch = [i for i in search_criteria3 if i in list2]
if listmatch:
    print("list 2 matches")
```

or

```
if listmatch:
    print("list 2 is the best choice")
else: print("no matches")
```

and repeating through the lists. I'm trying to find a way to get a closest match/best match.

edit: Defining best match at the moment as only number of criteria matched.

Comment: Can you explicitly define what you mean by `best match`? Is it just the greatest count of the matching items?

Comment: What exactly should be the result is in this example and why? What is the problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: You haven't defined "best match".  Research matching and distance algorithms.  Define your own similarity metric.  Then simply apply that to each possibility, and return the one with the highest score.

Comment: If you simply want a count of matching elements, then set intersection will get you the figure quite quickly -- and this question is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks mkrieger1 for the initial edit, ideal results would as mentioned in the first block of code. There's nothign wring with the code i've shown in the comprehensions, it only takes in a single search criteria though as search_criteria3 has only a single element. For multiple elements this will return all lists and have no "best factor". 
Thank you Prune, i'll look up what you've suggested and dig deeper

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function, that calculates similarity scores of the lists, and returns the highest similarity score.

```
def check(target, given_lists):
    max_score, ans = 0,0
    for num, given in enumerate(given_lists):
        score = 0
        for i in given:
            if i in target:
                score += 1
        if score>max_score:
            ans = num
    return num+1   #number of the current list

l1 = [...]
l2 = [...]
l3 = [...]
target_list = [...]
print(check(target_list, [l1,l2,l3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum([i==j for j in list3 for i in search_criteria2])
```

u can use the above fuction and get matching values then short according